# Is it possible to search content by date in combined field filter views?

Tags: views

Is it possible to search content by date in combined field filter views?

I have created a view in which content title ,content body and content date field is showing of node news type,i have added combined field filter for searching node in views but its searching by body and title but not by date .

What is the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Just make sure you have enabled the **Date Views** module (part of the [**Date**](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) project).